# Upgrading rails from MySql 5.7 to 8.0 but connection always tries to use TLS/SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql-8.0

The existing Rails 6.1 application needs to be upgraded to use MySql 8.0 - currently using 5.7

On development I've installed via brew MySql 8.0.
Unfortunately rails fails to connect to the local server with the error:

`TLS/SSL error: No such file or directory (2) (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)`

In config/database.yml I've used:

```
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8mb4
  ssl_mode: :disabled
  sslverify: false
```

yet it still appears to be attempting to use an SSL/TLS connection.

Gem versions:

rails: 6.1.7.6

mysql: 0.5.5

I've use bundle to force reinstall all gems.

Is there anything else I need to do to prevent it trying to use TLS/SSL for the connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Later versions of MacOS no longer distribute a linkable OpenSSL library. It is common to use Homebrew or MacPorts to install OpenSSL. Make sure that both the Ruby runtime and MySQL client libraries are compiled with the same OpenSSL family, 1.0 or 1.1 or 3.0, since only one can be loaded at runtime.

```
$ brew install openssl@1.1
$ gem install mysql2 -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)
```

More in [the mysql gem docs](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2?tab=readme-ov-file#mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks just tried that, rebuilt the gem against openssl1.1, but the issue persists.
The problem seems to be that the ssl_mode is being ignored and a TLS/SSL connection is being attempted.

Comment: By rebuilding it with the options, if that was the case, then it shouldn't be an issue - it should be able to connect over TLS. Maybe try removing those options, and/or try connecting through the socket file instead.

Comment: I've added tls-version='' to my.cnf, restarted MySql, and can now connect. It seems that despite rails configured not to use ssl, the database server was insisting on it. ‍♂️

Thanks for your suggestions. 

Answer (score 0):

Solved by turning off tls/ssl requirement in MySql:

my.cnf

```
tls-version = ''
```

Not sure why this works but am thinking it removed a mandatory requirement from the MySql server to use a TLS/SSL connection.